# Error in optimization with R

Tags: r, optimization

I have a Log-likelihood like this,

```
l(parameter)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \delta log[1-exp{-t^{\alpha} e^{x'\beta}}]-(1-\delta)t^{\alpha} e^{x'\beta}
```

I want to optimize in using R. I have tried it this way, but it is showing an error!

```
    #data: 
    time status  x 
    55     1     1 
    1      0     1 
    6      0     0 
    24     0     0 
    42     1     0   
    35     1     1 
# log-likelihood
mle.logreg = function(para, data){
    alpha <- para[1]
    x <- as.matrix(model.matrix(~data$x)[-1])
    beta <- as.matrix(rep(para[2],nrow(x)), ncol=1)
    delta <- data$status
    time <- data$time
    l1 <- delta*log(1-exp(-(time^alpha)*exp(t(x)%*%beta)))    
    l2 <- (1-delta)*((time^alpha)*exp((t(x)%*%beta)))
    loglik <- sum(l1-l2)
    return(-loglik)
}
fit <- optim(para=c(0.001,0.001),mle.logreg,data=dat1)
```

Here is the error.

```
Error in optim(para = c(0.001, 0.001), mle.logreg, data = dat) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
In optim(para = c(0.001, 0.001), mle.logreg, data = dat1) :
  one-dimensional optimization by Nelder-Mead is unreliable:
use "Brent" or optimize() directly
```

How can I solve this? Could any body give me solution?

Comment: In the `optim` call, the first argument `para` should be renamed to `par` or used without a name.

Comment: I think that there might also be some problem with variable names in your ```mle.logreg``` function. Seems like ```par1``` and ```par``` are not defined, while ```alpha``` and ```beta``` are not used. I had to change the names for those variables (and used the correct name for the ```par``` argument) to get this to work.

Comment: @mvkorpel Thanks for your valuable and effective suggestions.

Comment: @DGKarlsson Thanks for corrections.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This was a pretty good post, though I did fix a couple things. First, there where some words missing from the sentences in the body of the question, so I added those in; it makes it more readable. Second, I separated the code block from the error so they are distinguishable. Lastly, I deleted the closing, as this is distracting when reading the question. I hope you get your answer!

Comment: just a word of caution regarding @mvkorpel suggestion to rename `para` into `par`: `par` is a function to set or get graphical parameters, and it's always ill adviced to name variables after existing functions...

Comment: @PavoDive `par` is the name of the first argument in `optim`.

Comment: Please paste the output of `dput(dat1)` into the question to make it easily reproducible by others.